# How do I test a method in a typescript?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

Tell me, how do I test the distanceCalculation () method?
I want to check the accuracy of the result in the test with precisely specified values.
How in the Jest to test the methods of the Typescript?
This is a test task and I'm just learning.

```
class Car {
  amountOfFuel: number;
  fuelСonsumption: number;

    constructor(carAmountOfFuel: number,
      carFuelСonsumption: number) {
        this.amountOfFuel = carAmountOfFuel;
        this.fuelСonsumption = carFuelСonsumption;
      }

      distanceСalculation(): number {
        return (this.amountOfFuel / this.fuelСonsumption)*100;
    }
}

export class Bentley extends Car {
  }

export class Zhiguli extends Car {
  }
```

test code

```
import { Bentley, Zhiguli } from './sum'

test("property check Bentley", () => {
  let car1 = new Bentley(90, 12);

  expect(car1).toHaveProperty('amountOfFuel',90);
  expect(car1).toHaveProperty('fuelСonsumption', 12);
});

test("property check Zhiguli", () => {
  let car2 = new Zhiguli(40, 10);

  expect(car2).toHaveProperty('amountOfFuel',40);
  expect(car2).toHaveProperty('fuelСonsumption', 10);
});
```

Comment: call the methods and check the return value or what exactly do you have trouble with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If distanceCalculation should be accessible from outside the class make sure to mark it public.

You can call it and check the returned value from within your tests like this:

```
test("Bentley", () => {
  const car1 = new Bentley(90, 12);

  expect(car1).toHaveProperty('amountOfFuel',90);
  expect(car1).toHaveProperty('fuelСonsumption', 12);

  expect(car1.distanceСalculation()).toBe(750);
});

test("Zhiguli", () => {
  const car2 = new Zhiguli(40, 10);

  expect(car2).toHaveProperty('amountOfFuel',40);
  expect(car2).toHaveProperty('fuelСonsumption', 10);

  expect(car2.distanceСalculation()).toBe(400);
});
```